# Bubble up Exception from Task.Run()

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task

I have the code below and I am trying to bubble out the exception coming out from testFunction(). When i try to run the code there is no exception thrown.

testFunction is a task which i want to call in regular interval

However if I explicitly add throw new CustomException(); inside the Task.Run, the code throws correctly. I am unable to understand this behavior. I CANNOT await or wait the Task.Run because i want the task.Run to run independently on it own, hence I am using ContinueWith but continueWith is not catching the exception and hence not throw it. Please advise what am i missing here?

```
public class Example
{

   public static CancellationTokenSource source = new CancellationTokenSource();
   public static void Main()
   {
       Console.WriteLine("Hello start");
       Task.Run(async () => 
       {

           while(token.IsCancellationRequested)
           {
               token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
               await testFunction(source.Token); 
               await Task.Delay(1000,token);                   
           }
                       
       } ).ContinueWith((t) =>
                        {                                
                           if (t.Exception != null) throw t.Exception;
                        });
   }
      
   public static async Task testFunction(CancellationToken token)
   {
       throw new CustomException();

   }
}
```

Comment: There are several things wrong with your code: 1) you don’t need the Task.Run, because `testFunction` is already async. 2) You don't need the ContinueWith, because exceptions would bubble up automatically. 3) You don’t await your task. Therefore your program will end before the task ends and even if not your exceptions get swallowed. Either mark `Main` as async or call the Wait() method on your task. Your Main method will still run concurrently up until wherever you put the `await` or `Wait`.

Comment: I need to call testFunction at regular interval hence the need for a infinite loop.

Comment: But you still, don't need the Task.Run, because the asynchronicity is done by Task.Delay. If you do `public static async Task Main() { var task = testFunctionWithWhileLoop(...); MyOtherProgramCode(); await task; }` your task with the while loop will run in the background while your other program code runs concurrently alongside to it.

Answer (score 1):

> I CANNOT await or wait the Task.Run because i want the task.Run to run independently on it own

You must use `await` to observe the exception. You don't have to use `await` right away, though. You can save the `Task` in a variable and `await` it later if you want.

> hence I am using ContinueWith

`ContinueWith` is not going to do anything that `async`/`await` can't do. `ContinueWith` won't help you. [It should actually almost never be used](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/10/continuewith-is-dangerous-too.html).

> I am trying to bubble out the exception coming out from testFunction().

Let me turn this around: where is the exception *going*? Where is it bubbling *to*? **Which part of the code is going to observe that exception**? Once you answer that question, you'll find where to put your `await`.

Comment: The way this was written was especially helpful to me in understanding the meaning of "await" in this context.